# find: paths must precede expression: 2

Tags: bash, find

```
$ find .  -type f -depth 2  -iname '2mm*'
find: paths must precede expression: 2
```

What is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-depth` enables depth-first searching. It doesn't take any arguments. You probably want `-mindepth 2` or `-maxdepth 2`.

From the [find(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> ```
> -depth
> ```
>
> Process each directory's contents before the directory itself. The `-delete` action also implies `-depth`.
>
> ```
> -maxdepth levels
> ```
>
> Descend at most `levels` (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below > the command line arguments. `-maxdepth 0` means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.
>
> ```
> -mindepth levels
> ```
>
> Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than `levels` (a non-negative integer). `-mindepth 1` means process all files except the command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks John. It solved my problem. I was using -depth instead of -maxdepth.